# Import "vk_api" could not be resolved, Error importing packages and libraries

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm new to Python, and I've never programmed before, but recently I started to get involved in this topic. I'm trying to make an application for listening to and downloading music from VK, for this I use the vk_api library. I also turned to the ChatGPT neural network to write the code
I tried in every possible way to find syntax errors, there were only a couple of them (I ruled through a special site). The vk_api and PyQt5 libraries were installed through the terminal. The code is not run through the terminal, not through VScode. Here's the actual code.If you find any more errors, I will be very grateful to you.

```
import sys
import vk_api
import requests
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal

# Installing the application icon
app_icon = QIcon(r'C:\Program Files\vkloader\Icon.png')
# Stream class for loading audio recordings
class DownloadMusicThread(QThread):
    downloadProgress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DownloadMusicThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.credentials = None
        self.playlist_id = None
        self.audio_ids = []
        self.download_dir = None

    def set_credentials(self, login, password):
        self.credentials = (login, password)

    def set_playlist_id(self, playlist_id):
        self.playlist_id = playlist_id

    def set_audio_ids(self, audio_ids):
        self.audio_ids = audio_ids

    def set_download_dir(self, download_dir):
        self.download_dir = download_dir

    def run(self):
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(*self.credentials)
        vk_session.auth()
        vk = vk_session.get_api()

        if self.playlist_id is not None:
            audios = vk.audio.get(owner_id=self.credentials[0], playlist_id=self.playlist_id)
            audio_ids = [audio['id'] for audio in audios['items']]
            self.audio_ids = audio_ids

        num_audios = len(self.audio_ids)
        for i, audio_id in enumerate(self.audio_ids):
            try:
                audio = vk.audio.getById(audio_id=audio_id)[0]
                audio_url = audio['url']
                artist = audio['artist'].replace('/', '_')
                title = audio['title'].replace('/', '_')
                filename = "{} - {}.mp3".format(artist, title)
                filepath = os.path.join(self.download_dir, filename)

                response = requests.get(audio_url, stream=True)
                with open(filepath, "wb") as audio_file:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        audio_file.write(chunk)

                progress = int((i + 1) / num_audios * 100)
                self.downloadProgress.emit(progress)
            except Exception as e:
              print("Error downloading audio %s: %s" % (audio_id, e))

# Main window class
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('VK Music Downloader')
        self.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

        # Окно ввода логина и пароля
        login_label = QAction('Логин:', self)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        login_label.setFont(font)
        login_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.addToolBarBreak()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Вход')
        self.toolbar.addAction(login_label)
        self.login_edit = self.toolbar.addLineEdit()
        password_label = QAction('Пароль:', self)
        password_label.setFont(font)
        password_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.toolbar.addAction(password_label)
        self.password_edit = self.toolbar.addLineEdit()
        self.password_edit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.toolbar.addAction('Войти', self.login_check)

        # Window to select a playlist or specific audio recordings
        download_label = QAction('Из плейлиста:', self)
        download_label.setFont(font)
        download_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.addToolBarBreak()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Загрузка')
        self.toolbar.addAction(download_label)
        self.playlist_radio = self.toolbar.addRadioButton('Плейлист')
        self.playlist_radio.toggled.connect(self.toggle_playlist_field)
        self.playlist_field = self.toolbar.addComboBox()
        self.playlist_field.setDisabled(True)
        self.toolbar.addAction('Обзор...', self.open_file_dialog)
        self.audios_radio = self.toolbar.addRadioButton('Аудиозаписи')
        self.audios_radio.toggled.connect(self.toggle_audios_field)
        self.audios_field = self.toolbar.addLineEdit()
        self.audios_field.setDisabled(True)

# Window for selecting the download directory
        folder_label = QAction('Сохранять в:', self)
        folder_label.setFont(font)
        folder_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.addToolBarBreak()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Сохранение')
        self.toolbar.addAction(folder_label)
        self.folder_edit = self.toolbar.addLineEdit()
        self.toolbar.addAction('Обзор...', self.open_dir_dialog)

# Start download button
        self.addToolBarBreak()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Начало загрузки')
        self.download_button = self.toolbar.addAction('Загрузить')
        self.download_button.setDisabled(True)
        self.download_button.triggered.connect(self.start_download)

        # Associating the Music Download Stream with the Main Window Signals
        self.download_thread = DownloadMusicThread()
        self.download_thread.downloadProgress.connect(self.update_progress)

# Checking the correctness of the login and password
    def login_check(self):
        login = self.login_edit.text().strip()
        password = self.password_edit.text().strip()
        if not login or not password:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Введите логин и пароль')
            return
        self.download_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.playlist_field.clear()
        try:
            vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
            vk_session.auth()
            vk = vk_session.get_api()
            playlists = vk.audio.getPlaylists()
            for playlist in playlists['items']:
                self.playlist_field.addItem(playlist['title'], playlist['id'])
        except vk_api.AuthError:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Не удалось авторизоваться')
            return
        self.playlist_field.setEnabled(True)
        self.download_button.setEnabled(True)

# Switch between playlist selection and specific audio recordings
    def toggle_playlist_field(self, checked):
        self.playlist_field.setEnabled(checked)
        self.audios_field.setDisabled(checked)

    def toggle_audios_field(self, checked):
        self.audios_field.setEnabled(checked)
        self.playlist_field.setDisabled(checked)

    # Opening the dialog for selecting a playlist or files with audio recordings to download
    def open_file_dialog(self):
        if self.playlist_radio.isChecked():
            self.playlist_field.showPopup()
        else:
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
            filenames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выбрать аудиозаписи для загрузки", "",
                                                        "Аудио файлы (*.mp3);;Все файлы (*)", options=options)
            if filenames:
                self.audios_field.setText("\n".join(filenames))

    # Opening the dialog for selecting a directory to save files
    def open_dir_dialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        foldername = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выбрать директорию для сохранения", options=options)
        if foldername:
            self.folder_edit.setText(foldername)

# Start downloading music
    def start_download(self):
        login = self.login_edit.text().strip()
        password = self.password_edit.text().strip()
        if not login or not password:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Введите логин и пароль')
            return

        if self.download_thread.isRunning():
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Загрузка уже запущена')
            return

        self.download_thread.set_credentials(login, password)

        if self.playlist_radio.isChecked():
            playlist_index = self.playlist_field.currentIndex()
            if playlist_index >= 0:
                playlist_id = self.playlist_field.itemData(playlist_index)
                self.download_thread.set_playlist_id(playlist_id)
        else:
            audio_ids = [audio_id.strip() for audio_id in self.audios_field.toPlainText().split('\n')]
            self.download_thread.set_audio_ids(audio_ids)

        download_dir = self.folder_edit.text().strip()
        if not download_dir:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Выберите директорию для сохранения')
            return
        self.download_thread.set_download_dir(download_dir)

        self.download_thread.start()

# Updating the loading indicator
    def update_progress(self, progress):
       self.statusBar().showMessage("Загружено %s%%" % progress)
       if progress >= 100:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Загрузка завершена', 'Файлы успешно загружены')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationDisplayName('VKloader')
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to reinstall python, reinstalled the libraries: pip, PyQt5, but the script does not start. VScode also swears at some errors that I did not find.